# where is the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider source

Tags: asp.net-membership

I had heard a rumour that the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider source code was available.

I'm having some difficulty troubleshooting the our setup of the out-of-the-box provider, and stepping through the source would have been really handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the entire source to the .NET framework using the [.NET Framework Mass downloader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/netmassdownloader.aspx) available at CodeProject.  You can find more information on how to use and download it from Microsoft at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/.

Answer (score 1):

turns you can download the source (delivered as an MSI) from 
[Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).  How cool is that!